# .Net Core v. 1.1.0 not found

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to reverse engineer an existing database using EF Core in a .Net Core class library project.

Here's the `project.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```
PM> scaffold-dbcontext "data source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -verbose
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.0.1
      1.1.0-preview1-001100-00
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.0'.
Process finished with non-zero exit code
```

This is while I have targeted the 1.1.0 of .Net.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As error log says, you do not have 1.1.0 version of .NET Core installed on your machine. This version is needed by `scaffold-dbcontext` tool, that is part of .NET Core CLI,  not part of your application and therefore doesn't use nuget packages from your app.

To install .NET Core 1.1.0 go to [.NET Core Download](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current/sdk) page and select `x86/x64` version that you need. After that, you will have new '1.1.0' folder in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App`, that is the default place for the .NET Core framework.

Comment: Did you check the images I included??

Comment: @Arrrr yes, and as I said - nuget package is not what is needed. You should have framework to be installed (check your `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` folder).

Comment: please make an edit to your post so that I can take back my down vote.

Comment: I had same issue even having all references to Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0. Installing 1.1.7 solved it. Thanks.

Comment: @Set +1 for the great answer. A side note/question - Isn't it necessary to install also the .NET Core Runtime in this case ? Thanks !!

Comment: @GuyAvraham actually runtime is shipped with [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/sdk). So if you install SDK, you will have the runtime as well. Thought not vice versa.